# passing protocol into completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

good morning stack overflow, I have some code written below that is an excerpt from a project where the primary objective is to become more familiar with networking in swift4/iOS and to build more intuition and comfort with completion handlers and closures. My intentions with this program were to create a generic of sorts where I could pass any object into JSONDecoder() as long as it conformed to decodable/codable. For example, I wanted to write something similar to this, so I could make any struct/class and as long as it conforms to codable/decable I would be able to pass it into the function and have JSONDecoder().decode, work its magic and spit that data into the completion handler so I can use it however I want.

```
typealias jsonTaskCompletionHandler = (_ decodableObject: Decodable) -> Void

func getData(with url : String, completionHandler completion: @escaping jsonTaskCompletionHandler){
    let newURL = URL(string: url)
    self.session.dataTask(with: newURL!) { (data, _, _) in
        guard let data = data else {return }
        print(data)
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(decodableObject.self, from: data)
            return completion(decodableObject)
        } catch {
            print("decoding error")
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

instead, I'm hardcoding the type 'jsonStructure' to make it work.

```
typealias jsonTaskCompletionHandler = (jsonStructure) -> Void

func getData(with url : String, completionHandler completion: @escaping jsonTaskCompletionHandler){
    let newURL = URL(string: url)
    self.session.dataTask(with: newURL!) { (data, _, _) in
        guard let data = data else {return }
        print(data)
        do {
            let jsonData = try    JSONDecoder().decode(jsonStructure.self, from: data)
            return completion(jsonData)
        } catch {
            print("decoding error")
        }
        }.resume()

}
}

    @IBAction func getData(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("button press")
    let networkCL = networkClient()
    networkCL.getData(with: "someURL") { (objectThatConformsToCodable)   in
        print(objectThatConformsToCodable)
    }
}
```

To make the question more clear. I want to pass any data structure/Object that conforms to codable into JSONDecoder().decode and have the completion handler return the JSON data as an instance of the object that is conforming to codable, instead I'm hard coding the specific data type into

```
data = JSONDecoder.decode(dataType.self) 
completion(data)
```

whereas I'd just like to pass in

```
data = JSONDecoder.decode(anyDataStructureThatIsCodable.self)
completion(data)
```

any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is about specific questions and answers. I can't really identify a concrete question in your post other than "what do you think about my code?". https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be better fitted for your request, but I'm not familiar with their rules, so be sure to check out their help pages first, if you consider posting there.

Comment: Maybe I should make the question more clear... "I wanted to write something similar to this, so I could make any struct/class and as long as it conforms to codable/decable I would be able to pass it into the function and have JSONDecoder().decode, work its magic and spit that data into the completion handler so I can use it however I want.". I want to pass any data structure/Object that conforms to codable into JSONDecoder().decode and have the completion handler return the JSON data as an instance of the object that is conforming to codable.